# Clojure specter merge navigated value with other map

Tags: clojure, specter

I try to use Clojure specter to edit my orders information from "database". This application is base on Rest API.

My API call:

```
(PUT "/orders" []
         :return :specs.models.order/orderSpec
         :body-params [orderid :- :specs.models.order/orderid
                       {amount :- :specs.models.order/amount (orderController/getAmount orderid)}
                       {description :- :specs.models.order/description (orderController/getDescription orderid)}
                       {productid :- :specs.models.order/productid (orderController/getProductid orderid)}]
         :summary "Edits the description and/or amount and/or productid of an order"
         (getResponseFromContent (orderController/editOrder orderid amount description productid))
         )
```

This is my "database":

```
      [{:orderid 0 :productid 0 :description "A" :amount 2 :state "active"}
        {:orderid 1 :productid 1 :description "A" :amount 2 :state "active"}]
```

It's in the different file and I use this to call it in model

```
(def filename "resources/mockorderDatabase.dat")
(def database (atom (try
                      (clojure.edn/read-string (slurp filename))
                      (catch Exception e []))))
```

This is my controller:

```
(defn editOrder
  "Edit order's description and/or amount and/or productid by orderid"
  [orderid amount description productid]
  (if-let [editedorder (order/edit-order db/config {:orderid orderid :amount amount :description description :productid productid})]
    (first editedorder)
    nil))
```

and I am stuck with `edit-order`. How should I make it works?

So far what I came up with the `edit-order`:

```
(defn edit-order                                           
  [db orderid amount description productid]
  (->> (transform [ALL (comp (partial = orderid) :orderid)]
                  #(assoc % :productid productid :amount amount :description description)
                  @database
       )
   )
  )
```

the response i got is:

```
{
  "type": "unknown-exception",
  "class": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"
}
```

Would be better if I use `setval` instead of `transfrom`?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: It is very confusion that you have both `editorder` and `edit-order` (you don't need both). And, you call `edit-order` with `db/config` and a map, but the arglist takes 5 params (perhaps missing destructuring?). Also you don't show the `require` expressions, nor the function call. Also, what is `db/config`? What is the `order` namespace? You need to put everything in the question.

Comment: You may need to review the basics a bit instead of thrashing about at random. The books Living Clojure and Brave Clojure are good starting points.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need Specter for this:

```
(def data
  [{:orderid 0 :productid 0 :description "A" :amount 2 :state "active"}
   {:orderid 1 :productid 1 :description "A" :amount 2 :state "active"}])

(defn update-by-orderid [orders orderid description amount productid]
  (vec
    (for [order orders]
      (if (= orderid (:orderid order))
        (assoc order          ; change if match
          :description description
          :amount amount
          :productid productid)
        order))))                 ; return unchanged if no match


(update-by-orderid data 0 "DESC" 99 123) =>
[{:orderid 0,
  :productid 123,
  :description "DESC",
  :amount 99,
  :state "active"}
 {:orderid 1,
  :productid 1,
  :description "A",
  :amount 2,
  :state "active"}]
```

Comment: No point in overcomplicating things by unnecessarily using a library. +. I will say though that if you have a guarantee that IDs will be unique, a slightly more complicated solution that has an early exit would be better. This solution iterates the rest of the collection even once an ID has been found. `loop` would probably be fairly clean here.

Comment: I couldn't guarantee that an order-id might not appear more than once. Else the containing vector could have been a map from order-id to order details.

Comment: True. I've seen a lot of people using vectors of maps containing ids that are unique in previous questions though, and they don't seem to take to the suggestion to make the enclosing vector a map instead. I was assuming this string of similar questions all came from the same class or something.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Just trying to understand the code... [orders orderid description amount productid] and Orders here means the database?

Comment: Yes, when it is used, we call `(update-by-orderid data ...)` so the db `data` is passed as the 1st argument and becomes `orders` inside the function.

Comment: It doesn't work. Maybe it's because 'edit-orders' takes maps as argument not just numbers or strings?

Comment: Please update the question with sample code, sample data, & the results (output or error msgs) if something isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
(def filename "mockorderDatabase.dat")
(def database (atom (try
                        (clojure.edn/read-string (slurp filename))
                        (catch Exception e []))))

(require '[com.rpl.specter :refer :all])

(defn change-order [*database id productid amount desc]
    (transform [ATOM ALL (comp (partial = id) :orderid)]
               #(assoc % :productid productid :amount amount :description desc)
               *database))

(prn (change-order database 0 111 222 "XXXX-YYYY"))
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question.  The  "database" I used is in the different file.  Sorry, if I confused you.

Comment: `(defn edit-order                                         
      [db orderid description amount productid]
      (->> (transform [ALL (comp (partial = orderid) :orderid)]
                      #(assoc % :productid productid :amount amount :description description)
                      @database))`                                                                              I tried to modify ur code, but it doesn't work...